# Trazar todos los datos - Matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando dibujar un gráfico lineal con una lista de fechas "rango" como eje x y una lista de enteros "balance" como eje y
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de graficarlo omite algunas fechas

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4, 7), dpi = 70, constrained_layout = True)
ax = plt.plot(rango, balance)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay solo 7 fechas de las 17 que le pasé. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que grafique la totalidad de los datos?

Comment: Por favor pon el código y los datos en formato texto, en vez de en imagen. Esto nos da facilidades a los que te queremos ayudar, paraa reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajusta los datos en el eje x con `plt.xticks()`. matplotlib define los ticks tanto en `x` como en `y` de forma automática pero puedes especificar los ticks manualmente ingresando una lista de los ticks que quieres mostrar.

Toma en consideración que quizá vas a tener que rotar los textos en los ticks en x para que se puedan visualizar todos con la propiedad `rotation=degrees`